# how to Save data in sqlite from SQL server

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, sqlite

i have tried so much for establish connection,
i have used below code for this but it doesn't work.
please help me.
Thanks in advance..

```
public DBConnector(Context context)
{
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
connect = CONN("username", "password", "db name", "sql_server_ip");
}enter code here

private Connection CONN(String _user, String _pass,String _DB, String _server)
{
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy= new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
Connection conn=null;
String ConnURL=null;
try
{
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" ).newInstance();
ConnURL= "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + _server + ";" + "databaseName=" + _DB + ";user=" + _user + ";password=" + _pass + ";";
conn=DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
Log.d("connection", "open");
}
catch(SQLException se){
Log.d("ERROR1", se.getMessage());}
catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
Log.d("ERROR2", e.getMessage());}
catch(Exception e){
Log.d("ERROR3", e.getMessage());}
return conn;
}
```

Comment: Please read; http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then try to reform your question. What are you intending to do? The only thing really obvious from your code is that you are trying to connect to a sql server. Are you getting any specific errors? Your title suggests that you want to migrate data from one server to another, however your code does not reflect any of that.

Comment: ok sorry for inconvenience..